# passive voice in a sentence

Tags: indirect-objects

They did not tell me anything about the matter.

> a) Nothing was told me about that matter.
>
> b) Nothing was told about this matter to me.

Which one is the correct answer? I prefer #b as ''about this matter '' is more important than ''to me''.

Comment: Your 'base' sentence is ungrammatical: it should be either *They did not **tell** me anything* or *They told me nothing*.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told nothing about the matter.

"They" is the subject of your original sentence.  "Nothing about the matter" is the direct object.  "Me" is the indirect object.

> They told me X. (active)
>   I was told X (by them) (passive, indirect object)
>   X was told to me (by them). (passive, direct object)

You could also say:

> Nothing about the matter was told to me by them.

but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's a confusing sentence.

Comment: Or *Nothing was told me by them* ... it's rare and old-fashioned, but grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are correct. The correct sentence would be

```
I was told nothing about this matter.
```

or

```
Nothing about this matter was told to me
```